# symfony2: form data signature

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I am rewriting an existing rest api to Symfony2. Of course I don't want to change the interface to the client.

previously we posted data to create a User resource like this:

```
{
    "name":"myName",
    "email":"myEmail"
}
```

In Symfony2.3, I pass the request to the form with $form->handleRequest($request). For the form to be submitted, the signature of the body must include the form type name, as:

```
{
    "user" : {
        "name":"myName",
        "email":"myEmail"
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to keep the previous signature, and still use Symfony forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one more person trying to use forms with REST...

The problem is that the Symfony forms' purpose is to bind data from an **HTML form** to a model object or array. Everything else — validation, for example — is done not by Symfony forms, but by dedicated services like `validator`. Symfony forms just delegate to those services for your convenience.

So, since you're doing REST and not using HTML forms, **stop using the wrong tool for the job**. Instead, use a serializer like [this one](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer) that has [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) to integrate with Symfony. You **can** do validation and other stuff without using Symfony forms by using the respective services directly.

Comment: okay, I'm using Symfony for the first time. Using forms for validation looked wrong to me, but people told me this was best practice.

Comment: Slap those people hard. At least for me. ;)

Comment: will try your suggestion. ps: other people who claim to know (http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/) use forms solely for validation. Anyway, I'm using the JMSSerializerBundle already for exporting resources as json. I might use it as well for importing them. Do you suggest to call the validator service directly from within the controllers? thanks

Comment: I do agree with @ElnurAbdurrakhimov Form component should only be used to bind data from an HTML form. (I removed my suggestion as Elnur's one is more relevant)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named form with an empty name:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->createNamed(null, 'user', $user);
```